# Order of Diffraction Bragg's law

Tags: condensed-matter, diffraction, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

Given the relation of Bragg's law $\sin\theta= \frac{n\lambda}{2d}$, this suggests that for a given wavelength $\lambda$ the order of diffraction is limited such that $\sin\theta$ is less than one. However, I have read in numerous sources that the order, n, can have any integer values. So how can one reconcile these two statements? does that mean only a certain number of fringes will be observed for a given wavelength?

Answer (score 1):

If $\sin(\theta)$ > 1, the order has an imaginary kz. So these orders are non propagating orders. The amplitude will vanish -after a few wavelength.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).